# Database Handling in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having some problems on my application since I'm not very experienced on the database handling, so far I've created my database with a table, and what I wanted to do is to show a specific data from the table as a variable.

My application has to do with chemical elements, therefore the table "elements" has all of them. I was thinking of making a random element generator using a random number to get any of the elements in the table with a query or something.

```
Random ra = new Random();
        int random_anumber = ra.Next(1, 9);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Francisco\Documents\FormData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM elements", con);
```

I was thinking on putting the random_anumber instead of the "*" but it's still not showing a single element. Since I don't know how to show them of convert the data into a variable.

Comment: Load them into a DataTable (research) and use your RNG to pick a random row.

Comment: Try using Linq-to-Sql , i think you will like it.

Comment: If you're working with something of limited size (less than a few thousand records) would suggest just putting everything into memory and work with it there, how many columns do you have?

Answer (score 4):

The "*" in the SQL statement is a field name selector and not a filter. So changing the * to something else won't limit your query to a single element. You have to add a where clause for that.

To solve this you can either use the SqlDataAdapter onto a DataSet and use the DataTable within the DataSet to grab a random row by using the random number as the index or run a simple query. I recommend running a query if all you need to do with this data is display a random element.

**--- Update ---**

**MS SQL Server Statement:**

> SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table
>   ORDER BY NEWID()

**MySQL Statement:**

> SELECT * FROM table
>   ORDER BY RAND()
>   LIMIT 1

The * is a wildcard character that select all columns/fields of the table. You can change the  to a comma delimited list of columns/fields you want to retrieve from the database.

Comment: I believe that `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` is a MySQL concept, rather than SQL Server which is what the OP is using. Although  to be fair, I see that the original tag was MySQL.

Comment: @DeanOC Ah, yes I based my answer on MySQL as that is what I saw as the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that the Table `elements` having a unique Key Field(let it be `element_id`) then you can access the Random Element by Specifying the ID in the Where Clause, Then your Query will be like The following:

```
string querySQL="SELECT * FROM elements Where element_id=@id";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querySQL, con) // con is the Connection
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", random_anumber);
// Get data using Adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it everyday:

Note: Here you can see that I use Sqlite in my example. You can use SQL by removing the Lites and using the right classes in SQL respectively.

```
string ConnectionString = "data source={0}; initial catalog={1}; integrated security=true; application name= <Your App Name>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient";

string DatabasePath = "<Your Path to your database>";

string commandstring = "SELECT * FROM elements";

using (SQLiteCommand MyCommand = new SQLiteCommand(commandstring, Connection))
 {
        using (SQLiteDataReader MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader())
           {
                    while (MyReader.Read())
                    {
 // Here is your result:
 // You can do anything that you want with it.
 // The 0 shows the first column. If your result returns more than one      column, //you can use other numbers like 1,2..n to get other columns out of your data //reader.
                        MyReader.GetString(0);
                    }
           }
}`
```

Comment: What is "DatabasePath" for?

Comment: In SQLite you can tell where to save your SQLite file. For example, this is my Database Path:             

DatabasePath = "C:\\MyAppName.s3db";

Comment: "Where is it used in your code?" was my real question.

Comment: I used it in my connection like this:
        Connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format(ConnectionString, DatabasePath));
        Connection.Open();